# Nth result in BigQuery Group By

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a derived table like:

```
id, desc, total, account
1, one, 10, a
1, one, 9, b
1, one, 3, c
2, two, 27, c
```

I can do a simple

```
select id, desc, sum(total) as total from mytable group by id
```

but I want to add the equivalent first(account), first(total), second(account), second(total) to the output so it'd be:

```
id, desc, total, first_account, first_account_total, second_account, second_account_total    
1, one, 21, a, 10, b, 9
2, two, 27, c, 27, null, 0
```

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, `desc`, total,
  arr[OFFSET(0)].account AS first_account, 
  arr[OFFSET(0)].total AS first_account_total,
  arr[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].account AS second_account, 
  arr[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].total AS second_account_total
FROM (
  SELECT id, `desc`, SUM(total) total, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(account, total) ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 2) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY id, `desc`
)
```

In cases when more than 2 first bins are required I would use below pattern that eliminates repeating of heavy repeated lines like `arr[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].total AS second_account_total`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NULL id, '' `desc`, NULL total, '' first_account, NULL first_account_total, '' second_account, NULL second_account_total) WHERE FALSE 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, `desc`, total, arr[OFFSET(0)].*, arr[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].* 
FROM (
  SELECT id, `desc`, SUM(total) total, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(account, total) ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 2) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY id, `desc`
)
```

In above, first line sets layout of output while returning no rows at all because of `WHERE FALSE`, so then I don't need to explicitly parse struct's elements and provide aliases